# Fortran shared library .so in parallel

Tags: dll, fortran, shared-libraries, mpi, fortran90

I have created a shared library `libtest.so` from a fortran code in linux. This `libtest.so` will be called from a parallel fortran code.

I am partitioning my simulation domain, and each processor does all the necessary operations required for its partitioned slab. It might be that one processor needs to call this `libtest.so` more than once for different objects. However, this shared library keeps some variables in memory and updates them each time depending also on the past values. Obviously, for each object I don't want to get updated based on the values of the other objects. So, each time this shared library is called should be linked with the object and not being mixed up with other objects.

Do you know how could I achieve this?

Comment: strictly speaking, you do not "call a library", but instead "call a function provided by a library". so your library is using global variables ? one option is to implement a reset-like subroutine that re-initialize all your global variables. an other option is to stop using global variables, and instead pass an extra parameter that describe a state. then always use the same state in order to keep the existing behavior, and use a new one if you do not want to use past values.

Comment: The functions in your library are not [thread safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). One solution is to encapsulate all the data in derived types and pass them explicitly to the functions.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet that's what i meant by 'calling a library', but good that you further clarified it.  No, it's not using global variables, but the library is being called each time step for different objects. So, if object 1 calls it at time step N, and then object 2 calls it at time step N, then object 2 will use some of the already stored variables in order to update its arguments. Passing an extra parameter would work, but then I need to reprogram all the variables so that they are array of equal size to the number of object, and I would rather avoid that (if possible)..

Comment: @PierredeBuyl even if I pass them as derived types, I don't see why it would be thread safe?

Comment: According to your description, you are using local variables with the `save` attribute, scoped either to the module or to a given function. Declaring the variables in the calling program means that there is a copy of your data for every "worker" in your code and so no overlap/conflict.

Comment: If you declare functions and subroutines as PURE or ELEMENTAL then it can help to ferret out where the problems are at.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl indeed I am using local variables with `save` attribute. These are though declared in the library that it is being called and not in the calling program.. that's why there appears a conflict.

Comment: Your comment confirms the situation. "library"-level variables are not thread-safe. See the wikipedia link I gave earlier.